# continuously watch files for changes

Tags: ant

I am new to Ant and I am trying to figure out how to create a target that would allow me to use ant to watch a set of files for changes and run specific ant commands when a change occurs.

So far I have this

```
<target name="watch">
  <outofdate>
    <sourcefiles>
      <fileset dir="${webapp.src.dir}/javascript" />
    </sourcefiles>
    <targetfiles />
    <sequential>
      <echo message="something changed" />
    </sequential>
  </outofdate>
</target>
```

My problem is that when I run it (`ant watch`) it "succeeds" end exits. I wanted it to keep running and wait for changes until I kill it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the third-party [`repeat`](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch24.html) task from the Antelope project:

```
<taskdef resource="ise.antelope.tasks.antelope.taskdefs"
              classpath="path_to_AntelopeJar"/>
   ...

<target name="watch">
    <!-- infinite count with 1 sec interval -->
    <a:repeat count="-1" interval="1">
        <outofdate>
           ...
        </outofdate>
    </a:repeat>
</target>
```